# TypeError: exit expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

I made a Python script to compare files (compareRFRegion). I call this script from a Perl script:

```
$cmd_return = `python compareRFRegion.py -c Working/channels_US_full.ini -r RF_US902_full`;
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compareRFRegion.py", line 355, in <module>
    input_filename, rf_region_filename)
  File "compareRFRegion.py", line 88, in open_files
    "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")
TypeError: exit expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Here's my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import re
import getopt

# Channel list from .ini
channel_list = []

# Channel list from RF_region.xml
rf_channel_list = []

# lgw list
lgw_list = []
rf_region_list = []


class Channel:

    """attributes
    - index
    - LC
    - subband
    - freqhz
    - usedforrx2

    """

    def __init__(self):

        self.index = 0        # [channel:x]
        #
        self.LC = 0           # name=LCx
        self.subband = 0      # subband=x
        self.freqhz = 0       # freqhz=x
        self.usedforrx2 = 0   # usedforrx2=x
        self.bandwidth = 0    # bandwidth=x
        self.power = 0        # power=x

    def display_channel(self):

        print("Channel #{} - LC{} - Subband = {} - Freq = {} - UsedForRX2 = {} - Power = {}\n".format(self.index,
                                                                                                      self.LC,
                                                                                                      self.subband,
                                                                                                      self.freqhz,
                                                                                                      self.usedforrx2,
                                                                                                      self.power))

    def __eq__(self, channel):

        # if self.LC != channel.LC:
        #     print ("LC different : {} - {} ", self.LC, channel.LC)
        # if self.subband != channel.subband:
        #     print ("Subband different : {} - {} ", self.subband, channel.subband)
        # if self.freqhz != channel.freqhz:
        #     print ("FreqHz different : {} - {} ", self.freqhz, channel.freqhz)
        # if self.usedforrx2 != channel.usedforrx2:
        #     print ("Usedforrx2 different : {} - {} ", self.usedforrx2, channel.usedforrx2)
        # if self.power != channel.power:
        #     print ("Power different : {} - {} ", self.power, channel.power)

        return self.LC == channel.LC and self.subband == channel.subband and self.freqhz == channel.freqhz and self.usedforrx2 == channel.usedforrx2 and self.power == channel.power

    def __ne__(self, channel):
        return not self.__eq__(channel)


# File handling

def open_files(input_filename, rf_region_filename):

    input_file = None
    lgw_file = None

    if input_filename:
        try:
            input_file = open(input_filename, "r")
        except IOError:
            sys.exit("Could not open", input_filename,
                     "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")

    try:
        rf_region_file = open(rf_region_filename, "r")
    except IOError:
        input_file.close()
        sys.exit("Could not open", rf_region_filename,
                 "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")

    return input_file, rf_region_file


def close_files(input_file, rf_region_file):

    input_file.close()
    rf_region_file.close()


# Read script arguments


def read_param(argv):

    channel_filename = ''
    rf_region_filename = ''
    lgw_filename = ''

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hc:l:r:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('compareRFRegion.py -c <channel_file> -r <RF_region_file>')
        print('compareRFRegion.py -l <lgw_file> -r <RF_region_file>')
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('compareRFRegion.py -c <channel_file> -r <RF_region_file>')
            print('compareRFRegion.py -l <lgw_file> -r <RF_region_file>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-c"):
            channel_filename = arg
        elif opt in ("-l"):
            lgw_filename = arg
        elif opt in ("-r"):
            rf_region_filename = arg
    # print('Channel file is "', channel_filename)
    # print('RF_region file is "', rf_region_filename)

    return channel_filename, lgw_filename, rf_region_filename

# process channel from RF_region.xml


def process_rf_channel(match, channel):

    global rf_channel_list

    if channel is not None:
        rf_channel_list.append(channel)

    channel = Channel()
    return channel


def process_rx2_LC(match, channel):

    global rf_channel_list

    if channel is not None:
        rf_channel_list.append(channel)

    channel = Channel()
    channel.LC = int(match.group(1))
    channel.usedforrx2 = 1
    return channel


def process_rf_freqhz(match, channel):

    channel.freqhz = int(float(match.group(1)) * 1000000)
    return channel


# process channel from channels.ini


def process_channel(match, channel):

    global channel_list
    # we store the previous channel in channel_list (except the first one)
    if channel is not None:
        channel_list.append(channel)

    channel = Channel()
    channel.index = int(match.group(1))
    return channel

# processes for all files


def process_LC(match, channel):

    channel.LC = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


def process_subband(match, channel):

    channel.subband = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


def process_freqhz(match, channel):

    channel.freqhz = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


def process_usedforrx2(match, channel):

    channel.usedforrx2 = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


def process_bandwidth(match, channel):

    channel.bandwidth = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


def process_power(match, channel):

    channel.power = int(match.group(1))
    return channel


# Read functions

def read_channels(channel_file):

    global channel_list

    actions = ((r"\[channel:(\d+)\]", process_channel),
               (r"name=LC((d)?.+)", process_LC),
               (r"subband=(\d+)", process_subband),
               (r"freqhz=(\d+\.\d+)", process_rf_freqhz),
               (r"usedforrx2=([0|1])", process_usedforrx2),
               (r"bandwidth=\$\{BW_(\d+)KHZ\}", process_bandwidth),
               (r"power=(\d+)", process_power))

    channel = None

    for line in channel_file:
        # print(line)
        for regex, action in actions:
            match = re.search(regex, line)
            if match:
                channel = action(match, channel)
                break

    # append the last channel in list
    if channel is not None:
        channel_list.append(channel)


def read_rf_region(rf_region_file):

    global rf_channel_list

    actions = ((r"<[RT]xChannel>", process_rf_channel),
               (r"<LC>(\d+)<\/LC>", process_LC),
               (r"<SB>(\d+)<\/SB>", process_subband),
               (r"<Frequency>(\d+\.\d+)<\/Frequency>", process_rf_freqhz),
               (r"<UsedForRX2>([0|1])<\/UsedForRX2>", process_usedforrx2),
               (r"<Bandwidth>(\d+)<\/Bandwidth>", process_bandwidth),
               (r"<RX2LC>(\d+)<\/RX2LC>", process_rx2_LC),
               (r"<RX2SB>(\d+)<\/RX2SB>", process_subband),
               (r"<RX2Freq>(\d+\.\d+)<\/RX2Freq>", process_rf_freqhz),
               (r"<RX2TxPower>(\d+)<\/RX2TxPower>", process_power))

    channel = None

    for line in rf_region_file:
        # print(line)
        for regex, action in actions:
            match = re.search(regex, line)
            if match:
                channel = action(match, channel)
                break

    # append the last channel in list
    if channel is not None:
        rf_channel_list.append(channel)


def read_rf_region_lgw(rf_region_file):

    global rf_region_list

    regexs = (r"<RFRegionId>(.+)<\/RFRegionId>",
              r"<LRR_power>(\d+)<\/LRR_power>")

    for line in rf_region_file:
        # print(line)
        for regex in regexs:
            match = re.search(regex, line)
            if match:
                rf_region_list.append(match.group(1))
                break


def read_lgw(lgw_file):

    regexs = (r"rfregionid=(.+)", r"power=(\d+)")

    global lgw_list

    for line in lgw_file:
        # print(line)
        for regex in regexs:
            match = re.search(regex, line)
            if match:
                lgw_list.append(match.group(1))
                break


# Compare functions

def compareChannels():

    for channel, rf_channel in zip(channel_list, rf_channel_list):
        if channel != rf_channel:
            # channel.display_channel()
            # rf_channel.display_channel()
            print(0)
            return

    print(1)


def compareLgw():

    for lgw_param, rf_region_param in zip(lgw_list, rf_region_list):
        if lgw_param != rf_region_param:
            # print(lgw_param)
            # print(rf_region_param)
            print(0)
            return

    print(1)

# def move_rx2_channel():

#     for i, channel in enumerate(rf_channel_list):
#         if channel.usedforrx2 == 1:
#             tmp = rf_channel_list.pop(i)
#             rf_channel_list.append(tmp)
#             return


#if __name__ == "__main__":

channel_filename, lgw_filename, rf_region_filename = read_param(sys.argv[
                                                                1:])
input_filename = ''
input_file = None
isChannelType = True

if channel_filename:
    input_filename = channel_filename
elif lgw_filename:
    input_filename = lgw_filename
    isChannelType = False

input_file, rf_region_file = open_files(
    input_filename, rf_region_filename)

# move_rx2_channel()

if isChannelType:
    read_rf_region(rf_region_file)
    read_channels(input_file)
    compareChannels()
else:
    read_rf_region_lgw(rf_region_file)
    read_lgw(input_file)
    compareLgw()

# print("List size is", len(channel_list))
# print("List rf size is", len(rf_channel_list))

# for channel, rf_channel in zip(channel_list, rf_channel_list):
#     channel.display_channel()
#     rf_channel.display_channel()

close_files(input_file, rf_region_file)
```

I am able to execute this in standalone in linux terminal by adding `if __name__ == "__main__":` (commented here). It works fine. But not by calling it from Perl. Maybe there is something I am missing about calling a Python script from Perl ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear about the error. Why are you calling `sys.exit()` with three arguments? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see the error was coming from sys.exit()... Sometimes the truth is screaming but we don't want to hear it. I'd better stay at home today :) Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
 sys.exit("Could not open", rf_region_filename,
             "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")
```

try

```
sys.exit("Could not open" + rf_region_filename + \
             "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")
```

adding in the commas isn't like the print statement, and doesn't concatenate them. Instead it treats the three strings as 3 different arguments. Adding in the additions signs will concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

Please, see - https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit
Your call of `sys.exit()` with 3 args is wrong, expected only one - exit code (optional)

Answer (score 1):

You twice call `sys.exit` with two many arguments (as the error tells you :) )

```
sys.exit("Could not open", input_filename,
                 "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")
```

change to e.g.

```
print("Could not open", input_filename,
                 "!!! Check it's in the current directory or the path is correct")
sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your exception. It says that you are calling `sys.exit()` with 3 arguments, but only 1 is allowed.

Read the docs on [`sys.exit([arg])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

And here is notes on optional argument `arg`:

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems require it to be in the range 0–127, and produce undefined results otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.

So you need to refactor your code, for `sys.exit` to get only one argument.